# results from loop in controller method displayed in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have a controller `TestController`

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def test_method
    for i in 1..5 do 
      <anything>
    end
  end
end
```

and I have a view for that controller

```
[...]
<%= controller.test_method() %>
[...]
```

when I call my view it sais

```
1..5
```

can anybody tell my why this is? thanks!!

Comment: See answer below. Food for thought: leave the parenthesis off and just write `controller.test_method`. The parenthesis aren't required, and in fact are misleading because if you put anything in there you're going to get an argument error. This is one of those things about ruby that is weird at first when you're coming from another language, but you'll get used to it. Some of Ruby's power and expressiveness lies in the fact that there is no such thing as a property vs. a method, everything in dot notation is a method call. The more you get comfy with that the more you can harness it for good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you told ERB to print the result of the expression, using `<%= ... %>`.

If you want the expression to be performed without the result being printed, leave off the equals sign.

```
<% my_expression %>
```

Comment: +0.5 for explicitly mentioning what I hinted at. But SO rounds up.

Answer (score 3):

Because `for i in 1..5` returns `1..5`.

If you want to do something over that `1..5` then you should make the method a helper, do the `1..5` in the view, or something more closely-related to the view layer functionality you're seeking.

IMO view-layer manipulations shouldn't call *back* into the controller that's rendered the view template in the first place; that's pretty counter-intuitive. The best approach depends on what you're actually doing.

---

Let me amend that. I don't find calling back into the controller intrinsically *wrong*, I just don't think the *result* of that call should be doing stuff to the render itself. Grabbing a value, doing a calculation, etc. are less onerous, although I'd argue in general that functionality still belongs somewhere else.

I may be in the minority here, though.